# Why is QListView slower than QListWidget?

Tags: python, performance, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistview

I have a variable like `a` in the code below that has a lot of data. I want to show this data in a QListWidget or QListView. I have been using QListWidget, but it consumes more memory than QListView, so I have chosen QListView.

But in the code below, the speed of showing QListView is slower than QListWidget. Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import time
app=QApplication([])
n=1000000

a=[]
for i in range(n):
     a.append('asfghjkg'+str(i))
class TodoModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, todos=None):
        super(TodoModel, self).__init__()
        self.todos = todos or []

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            # See below for the data structure.
            return self.todos[index.row()]
            # Return the todo text only.

    def rowCount(self, index): 
        return len(self.todos)    


todos = a
model = TodoModel(todos)

t=time.time()
win1=QListView()
win1.setUniformItemSizes(True)
win1.setViewMode(1)
win1.setWrapping(False)
win1.setFlow(QListWidget.TopToBottom)
win1.setModel(model)
win1.show()
print('show1',time.time()-t)
t=time.time()
win2=QListWidget()
win2.setUniformItemSizes(True)
win2.addItems(a)
win2.show()
print('show2',time.time()-t)
app.exec_()
```

Output on my PC is:

> show1 5.374950885772705
>   
>   show2 1.3125648498535156

Comment: This is not a good way to profile. Run your code with something like `python -m cProfile -s cumtime yourcode.py` and you will see where the time is being spent. Notice that it's not only in the millions of calls to `rowCount` and `len` as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the list-widget creates all the items in C++, whereas the list-view must make millions of Python method calls in your custom model. A flat, single-column tree-view is about twice as fast a list-view - but that's still significantly slower than the list-widget. For better performance, you could try implementing [fetchmore](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/itemviews/fetchmore.py). But this has the drawback of very slow scrolling, and you cannot easily navigate around the list (e.g. go straight to the last item). It also makes sorting and filtering much harder to implement.

If your data-set really is just a flat list of strings, you can achieve much better performance by using a [QStringListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html). This is because it's much simpler than the item-based model used by list-widget (and of course, it's implemented in C++, unlike your custom model). If I add the following code to your test script:

```
model2 = QStringListModel(todos)
t=time.time()
win3=QListView()
win3.setUniformItemSizes(True)
win3.setViewMode(1)
win3.setWrapping(False)
win3.setFlow(QListWidget.TopToBottom)
win3.setModel(model2)
win3.show()
print('show3',time.time()-t)
```

I get this output on my system:

```
show1 2.2652294635772705
show2 0.4205465316772461
show3 0.10054779052734375
```

So the stringlist-model is over four times faster than the list-widget in that scenario. However, if your actual requirements are more complex than that, you should probably consider using a database with an [sql-based model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-module.html).

Comment: Can you please comment on "A flat tree-view should be faster than a list-view - but it will still be slower than the list-widget."? Why is a flat tree view faster than a list-view? And why is the list view faster than a list-widget? What of that statement is meant to apply to c++ qt? And how/why is it true for python Qt? What do trees have to do with this at all?

Comment: A more robust approach to measuring performance is needed. Note that swapping the win1 and win2 sections in the OP's code does not result in a simple swap of their time profiles.

Comment: A single-column tree-view with no child items is exactly equivalent to a list-view. I tested it using the same script, and it is about twice as fast as a list-view when using both the custom model and the stringlist-model. The tree-view must be implemented differently, because it only makes about half the number of python method calls with the custom model. The list-view with a stringlist-model is faster than a list-widget because the list-widget uses a item-based model, which is less efficient (e.g. it consumes more memory).

Comment: @ekhumoro your method is a good idea, but it use nearly twice much memory than Pure QList View model.

Comment: @hpaalm Have you tried adding the strings directly to the model instead of creating a separate list first? If that doesn't make any difference, I suppose you just have to accept the trade-off: more speed == more memory.

Comment: @ekhumoro Maybe a single-column QTableView is as performant or more performant as a QTreeView? A QListView has support for things that might slow it down, such as horizontal layouting with wrapping, or icon-based layout with free-form positioning.